# How do I get a Google MapView to display more than just a grid?

Tags: android

When I run a simple MapView app, the map shows up as a grid - no image of countries like it should be.

I've read through several tutorials saying that I need to include Internet permissions as a child of my manifest tag in the Android Manifest, which I've placed in the file.

I also need to generate a fingerprint out of my debug.keycode file and register it with Google for a key, which I've done.  I've included this key in my XML layout.  Still, I only get a grid when I run the app.  I've registered my key a couple times and got the same result.  Has anyone else had and overcome this issue?  I've seen this same question posted under tutorials, but nobody had an answer.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here's the [official google tutorial](http://code.google.com/android/add-ons/google-apis/mapkey.html#getdebugfingerprint) to set this up. If you have gotten your key already I suggest you look at the section "Adding the Maps API Key to your Application". In there it tells you what attribute to include in your xml files in order to get the MapView to download the Google maps. Which is:

```
android:apiKey="example_Maps_ApiKey_String"
```

Hope this is what you were looking for.

Comment: Yeah, I have my key added as an element of my MapView already, but the app still just displays a grid.

Comment: Have you added `<uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />` in your AndroidManifest?

Comment: Yeah, I have that, too.  I'm wondering if my key is bad somehow.  I've re-registered it a couple times and I always get the same key back.

Comment: It's working now.  I made a new project and hooked it up the same way, but it gave me a map.  Thanks for the responses, Gix.  I'm sure you'll be hearing from me again soon.

Comment: glad to hear it's working. happy to help. btw welcome to Stackoverflow and remember to accept answers.